# Personal syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I tried to change the syntax highlighting, by copying `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim` to `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim`. Then I changed the syntax highlighting file, but I don't see any changes. `filetype` is set properly, and when I change something in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim`, I can see the changes. Is there anything I need to do to "activate" the `after/syntax` folder for highlighting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the syntax highlighting of a filetype by copying `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/<filetype>.vim` to your `~/.vim` directory, the proper place to copy it is `~/.vim/syntax/`, not `~/.vim/after/syntax/`. Vim will then use your syntax file *instead* *of* the one in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax`.

Your `~/.vim/after/syntax/` directory is the proper place for files that make relatively small tweaks to the syntax highlighting, such as changing the colors of highlight groups. The problem with making major changes in the `~/.vim/after/syntax/` directory is that the behavior of some of Vim's syntax rules depends on the order in which the rules are executed, and any rules in `~/.vim/after/syntax` are going to be executed *after* the rules in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax`.

I think the reason that the changes you make to `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim` are not showing up is because of this line near the bottom of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim`,

```
let b:current_syntax = "html"
```

and this block at the top of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim`, which is presumably still in your copy in `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim`:

```
if !exists("main_syntax")
  if version < 600
    syntax clear
  elseif exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
  endif
  let main_syntax = 'html'
endif
```

That block is detecting that `b:current_syntax` has already been set, so it terminates the script at that point by executing `finish`. None of your changes to that file are being executed.

To find where `$VIMRUNTIME` points to on your system, enter the command `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` in Vim.